# Unable to get mouse events to register in custom NSViewController

Tags: cocoa, nsresponder, responder-chain

Here's my code, simplified for brevity:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    var fooController: FooController!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

        self.fooController = FooController(frame: self.window.frame)

        self.window.contentViewController = self.fooController
        self.window.makeFirstResponder(self.fooController)
    }
}

class FooController: NSViewController {

    override func mouseUp(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        print("foo")
    }

    override func keyUp(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        print("bar")
    }
}
```

My `MainMenu.xib` has a single Window which you can see referenced above in AppDelegate.

When I press a button on my keyboard, I see "bar" in the console. When I click my mouse I see nothing. Once I click my mouse, no further key events are registered.

What am I missing? Why are mouse events stealing the responder chain away, and where is it going?

Comment: A mouse click can change the first responder. Do some reading: [Overview of Mouse Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH6-SW15)

Answer (score 0):

Like @Willeke mentioned, the first responder is probably changed through the mouse click.

You can set the first responder on mouse down like that:

```
override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
     self.view.window.makeFirstResponder(self)
}
```

Now you should be able to receive all events.